# Visual Studio no permite crear DataSet en Carpeta App_Data

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Estimados,
Necesito crear unos DataSet para mi aplicación en la Carpeta App_Data, pero al agregar el elemento no aparece la posibilidad de crear DataSet, en cambio si realizo la misma operación en otra carpeta si aparece la opción.

¿por que ocurre esto?

¿cual sería la solución o como compensarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exacto, no te permite ya que el uso de la carpeta App_Data es para poner una base de datos integrada o archivos de almacenamiento de datos como son por ejemplo los archivos XML y de texto.

Deberías crearlo en otro directorio o en la raíz del proyecto y todo ira de 10.

Saludos